# linode cloud server, symfony and phar

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssh, php53

Okay, So I've recently got a linode cloud server running Ubuntu 12.04.  I got it configured with the default symfony2.0 installation, but I've got a project that runs on the Symfony2.1 installation..

In my command line, when I run:  `php composer.phar install` it does nothing...

When I run `php -m` it shows me this:

```
[PHP Modules]
apc
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
ffmpeg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
suhosin
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

It shows `Phar` in there...  But no clue why it won't run the `.phar` file in the command line...  Any ideas?  If you need me to run any other command to help trouble shoot, please let me know which ones and I will do so post-haste.

Thanks..

Comment: I figured this out, but still not in the timeframe for me to answer my own question...

The resolution was adding:  suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar to the end of my php.ini file and it works like a charm.

Comment: You should be able to answer it by now.  :)